# Cannot Install QGIS Mapserver On Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: qgis-server

I'm trying to install qgis-mapserver on my ubuntu 12.04. I just installed qgis desktop 2.6.0-brighton successfully. Here is my steps when installed the desktop :

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties 
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass
```

But when I tried to install the mapserver :

```
sudo apt-get install qgis-mapserver libapache2-mod-fcgid
```

I got this error :

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
qgis-mapserver : Depends: qgis-providers (= 2.4.0-0precise2) but 2.6.0-0precise1 is to be installed
```

Comment: Using a "unstable" branch will could give you this kind of problems. 

I recommed you use (if you can, of course) "ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-stable" as repository, instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package is called "qgis-server" (no "map" part anymore) now.

Answer (score 1):

sudo apt-get install qgis-server

Comment: Welcome to the site abelouch.  It is highly recommended to add context to answers so that future readers can benefit from your post.  Otherwise, consider creating a comment.  To get fully up-to-speed on how GIS SE works, you can take the tour:  http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour