# Cannot install qgis-mapserver, on Deb8.3,' Dependencies issue'

Tags: installation, qgis-server, debian

I am trying to install qgis-mapserver.

I started at Qgis org Installers website - Latest Release   2.12.x Lyon,
with a fresh Debian 8.3 jessie install.

The repos's are as instructed, which gives me:
qgis-mapserver 2.4.0+jessie1, that depends on:
qgis-providers (=2.4.0+jessie1) but 1:2.12.3+13jessie is all I can install.

Do I need to install 2.8.x Wien, to avoid the issues??

Also, I've read:
"The package is called "qgis-server" (no "map" part anymore) now.",
by Michal Mackiewicz, in this two year old Q&A: [Cannot Install QGIS Mapserver On Ubuntu 12.04](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/121134/cannot-install-qgis-mapserver-on-ubuntu-12-04)

No recent notes at the Qgis website, or from other Debian users,
on this issue?

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling everything and reinstalling? There could have been glitch of some sort. The uninstall and reinstall might be a good start if you have tried installing dependencies and getting no where. I recently had a similar [experience](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/180067/opengeo-suite-installed-on-ubuntu-14-04-unable-to-proceed-delete-issues-with-de)  while trying to install OpenGeo Suite which has Geoserver.

Comment: Thx, I've gone thru the un/re-install process...I just tried repos change to wheezy...thinking versions should be proper. Didn't work. I'm gonna re-install and hope someone has a cure. I cannot be the only one presently having this version issue. There's still the question of Michal's reply!..?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Making Bug report #[14357](https://hub.qgis.org/issues/14357), confirmed Michal Mackiewicz's comment.

> Comment:The package was renamed to qgis-server

Issue closed. qgis-mapserver: pkg residue file.